Problems upgrading Drupal. The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later
I'm upgrading from Drupal 9.3.8 to version 10 and I got the typical white screen with the following message. Any idea how to fix it? I am new to Drupal.
Error: Class "Drupal\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection" not found in Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection() (line 460 of /home/aul/www/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php).
Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection('default', 'default') (Line: 191)
Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default')
call_user_func_array('Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection', Array) (Line: 77)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'database') (Line: 179)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('database', 1) (Line: 226)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 60)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'cache.container') (Line: 179)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.container') (Line: 576)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getCachedContainerDefinition() (Line: 965)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 515)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 739)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)```



give this a read https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3334213 https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3064787

Did you run "composer install"? Did you clear the cache after that (drush cr)?
